# History.js issue with ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pushstate, history.js

in my website i have found trouble with pushState function in internet explorer and i have replace it with History.js API class.
Now my function is:

```
// Push new history state
if (loc.hash !== hash) {
  //w.history.pushState(null, null, '#' + hash);
  w.History.pushState(null, null, '#' + hash);
}
```

But browser say:

> History.js does not support states with fragment-identifiers (hashes/anchors)

what's the problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try following as per the [doc](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) It should work...

```
History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4");
```

Comment: What's the solution if i've a url with # ?

Comment: Check out the documentation; it will become `www.mysite.com/#?state=4`